# Select ALL with Lambda and EF

Tags: c#, entity-framework, lambda

I have this that selects all cities:

```
ExecuteStoreCommand<MCT_DBEntities>("select * from cities", ConnectionResolver.DB_Connection);
```

Now I am trying to convert the to Lambda, but how do I tell it to `SELECT *`?

```
GetWithExpression<city, MCT_DBEntities>(u => u.SelectMany, ConnectionResolver.DB_Connection);
```

Edit:

```
   private static TValue RetryGetWithExpression<U,T, TValue>(Func<ObjectSet<T>, TValue> func, String connection, Int32 retryInfiniteLoopGuard = 0)
        where T : class
        where U : ObjectContext
    {
        Microsoft.Practices.TransientFaultHandling.RetryPolicy policy = RetryPolicyProvider.GetSqlAzureRetryPolicy();

        using (U entitiesContext = (U)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(U), new[] { connection }))
        {...}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your first parameter is `Expression<Func<T, bool>>` you may want:

```
RetryGetWithExpression<city, MCT_DBEntities>(_ => true, ConnectionResolver.DB_Connection);
```

**Edit.**
This should work:

```
RetryGetWithExpression<MCT_DBEntities, city, IQueryable<city>>(x => x.Select(y => y), 
                                        ConnectionResolver.DB_Connection);
```

Comment: This is my Func: Func<ObjectSet<T>, T> func

Comment: @user1662812 So it is selector? Then what about `x => x`?

Comment: Cannot convert lambda expression to delegate type 'System.Func<System.Data.Objects.ObjectSet<DataAccessComponents.EntityDataModels.city>,DataAccessComponents.EntityDataModels.city>'

Comment: @user1662812 can you show code of method `GetWithExpression`? it will make some sense.

Comment: Cannot convert lambda expression to delegate type 'System.Func<System.Data.Objects.ObjectSet<DataAccessComponents.EntityDataModels.city>,DataAccessComponents.EntityDataModels.city>' because some of the return types in the block are not implicitly convertible to the delegate return type

Comment: @user1662812, should be ok now.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
GetWithExpression<city, MCT_DBEntities>(u => u.Select(), ConnectionResolver.DB_Connection);
```

Comment: No overload for method 'Select' takes 0 arguments